# comparing dates in internet explorer using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have a function that compares two dates. If one is greater than the other, then the rest of the function is performed. The `detDate` variable is in the form **yyyy-mm-dd**. This works fine in Firefox and Chrome, but in Internet Explorer it only performs the 'else' part of the if statement.

Any suggestions on why, and how to fix it?

```
$(document).on('click','#confirm',function(){
          var now = new Date();
          now.setHours(0,0,0,0);
          var detDate=$("#detDate").val();
         var compareDate = new Date(Date.parse(detDate.replace(/-/g,', ')));
        if (detDate !== "") {

        if (compareDate>=now) {

         $.ajax({
              type:"post",
              url:"ajax/detention.php",
              data:"detDate="+detDate,
              success:function(response){
                 $("#comments3").html(response);
              }
          });

        }else {
            alert("You cannot select a date that has already passed!");
        }

        } else {
                alert("You must fill out all the empty information!");
            }

    });
```

Comment: What version of IE are you using and which version of jQuery?

Comment: What is `Internet Explorer`?

Comment: @Lauromine jQuery 1.11.3 and the latest internet explorer.

Comment: Did you try to `console.log` something in the if statement ? Is it displayed ?

Comment: @Lauromine nothing is displayed within the if-statement, IE just skips right over it.

Comment: I did not ask, is it the 1st or the 2nd if ? If the first, try replacing `if(detDate !== "")` by `if(detDate)`

Comment: the second if-statement, the first one is not an issue.

Comment: Have you tried slash separators instead of hythons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting the language preferences in your IE browser to the wanted format: Internet Options>General tab, 'Languages' button lists your language encoding preferences in order.
If it works, try setting the IE default format in you if statement parse it again in a new var and add an OR for it in your if statement.